# "The Magic", that Magisk isn't supposed to do

Tags: root-access, twrp, file-system, storage, magisk

I have magisk 24 which I futilely tried to downgrade  [using XDA's  guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/magisk-24-1-downgrade-warning.4395371/) but did not succeed, which is the 2nd part of my Question . There is something v interesting I note ( not sure how long its been with through various Magisk versions ) 
**So here are my questions**

```
 df -h /data
 Filesystem               1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/sbin/.magisk/block/data  22442480 18250808   4191672  82% /system/xbin/zcip
# If I try rm -f below file it says resource busy , which means that mount is actually using that file  
:/ # ls -al /system/xbin/zcip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1333960 2022-02-05 06:17 /system/xbin/zcip
olivelite:/ # $_ --help
BusyBox v1.30.1-osm0sis (2019-02-28 17:35:07 AST) multi-call binary.

Usage: zcip [OPTIONS] IFACE SCRIPT

Manage a ZeroConf IPv4 link-local address

    -f      Run in foreground
    -q      Quit after obtaining address
    -r 169.254.x.x  Request this address first
    -l x.x.0.0  Use this range instead of 169.254
    -v      Verbose

$LOGGING=none       Suppress logging
$LOGGING=syslog     Log to syslog

With no -q, runs continuously monitoring for ARP conflicts,
exits only on I/O errors (link down etc)

     # mount  |   grep -i 62
/dev/block/mmcblk0p62 on /data type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,resgid=1065,data=ordered)
```

`/data` partition is mounted on a file ( see above  I tried to peek in that file and its some kind of networkiing file ) ? wth ? ok before that /data was mounted on
this file `/data/app/*youtube*base.apk and /data/app/*youtubemusic*base.apk` both.
I cant get the log on screen of that since I uninstalled both these apps and after that
it showed up as above. While  the above 2 apps were installed it showed not
`/sbin/.magisk/block/data` but `/data` being mounted on these 2 apk. `df` showed the former apk while `mount`   command output showed  additionally `/data` being mounted on  the latter apk as well. */data being mounted on points that are actually files ?* I dont get it  ?

Whats happening and what can explain this. I am sure if I delete `/system/xbin/zcip`  it will  catch some other file to mount.  Has anyone w/ `magisk (24?)` had the same exp like this ?

2) I cant downgrade from `magisk 24` to `less then 24`. I totally uninstalled. Then installed patched 23 (and less) images via `TWRP` -I was left rootless. So I have 24 or no root.

Comment: 2. for downgrade uninstall apk, wipe cache partition and delete */data/adb* directory manually, then pick the json url from *raw.githubusercontent.com/topjohnwu/magisk-files* (or */magisk_files* <v21.4) and patch stock boot.img

Comment: "*`/data` partition is mounted on a file*". You need to understand at least two things: Linux bind mounts, and how Magisk uses bind mounts to be *systemless* and for Magisk modules.

Comment: this might help https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoTfl.jpg

Comment: yes it does. On the face of it al  appeared so "malwareish" ... thx. But  earlier it `bind mounted on /data/app/<app name>` . I see the idea of being system-less using this hack.